# Ruby - Getting page content even if it doesn't exist

Tags: ruby, host

I am trying to put together a series of custom 404 pages.

```
require 'uri'

def open(url)
 page_content = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
 puts page_content.content
end

open('http://somesite.com/1ygjah1761')
```

the following code exits the program with an error. How can I get the page content from a website, regardless of it being 404 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rescue from the error

```
 def open(url)
   require 'net/http'
   page_content = ""
   begin
     page_content = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))        
     puts page_content
   rescue Net::HTTPNotFound         
     puts "THIS IS 404" + page_content
   end
 end
```

You can find more information on something like this here: http://tammersaleh.com/posts/rescuing-net-http-exceptions/

Comment: This is not returning anything

Comment: it works for ruby-2.1.0. I added the explicit requirement, but you probably don't need that

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a possible way to parse that line by line to look for data? to check if page includes ("You broke it!")

Answer (score 0):

`Net::HTTP.get` returns the page content directly as a string, so there is no need to call `.content` on the results:

```
page_content = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
puts page_content
```

Comment: I believe that still generates an error if page respone is 404.. How do I override that?

Comment: i don't get any error when a 404 is encountered - perhaps its related to the version of ruby - what version are you using?